# Error in WordPress with a Gravatar

Tags: wordpress

comment.php

```
</div>
<div style="float:right;background:#333333;border-radius:5px;height:60px;width:60px;padding:2px;border:2px solid #111111;">
<?php echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, '60', $default=get_template_directory_uri().'/images/gravatar.gif'); ?>
</div>
```

functions.php

```
function prostayll_comment( $comment, $args, $depth )
{
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;
    echo "   <li ";
    comment_class( );
    echo " id=\"li-comment-";
    comment_id( );
    echo "\">\r\n     <div id=\"comment-";
    comment_id( );
    echo "\">\r\n      <div class=\"comment-author vbc\">\r\n         ";
    echo get_avatar( $comment->comment_author_email, "30", $default = get_template_directory_uri( )."/images/gravatar.gif" );
    echo "\r\n         ";
    printf( __( "<cite class=\"fn\">%s</cite> <span class=\"says\"> - </span>" ), get_comment_author_link( ) );
    echo "<s";
    echo "pan class=\"comment-time\">";
    echo prostayll_time( "comment" );
    echo " say:</span>\r\n      </div>\r\n      ";
    if ( $comment->comment_approved == "0" )
    {
        echo "         <em>";
        _e( "Your comment is awaiting moderation." );
        echo "</em>\r\n         <br />\r\n      ";
    }
    echo "\r\n      <div class=\"comment-meta commentmetadata\"><a href=\"";
    echo esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) );
    echo "\">";
    printf( __( "%1\$s" ), get_comment_date( __( "F j, Y" ) ) );
    echo "</a> 'scrie jos.";
    edit_comment_link( __( "(Edit)" ), "  ", "" );
    echo "</div>\r\n\r\n      ";
    comment_text( );
    echo "     </div>\r\n";
}
```

error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)
>   http://i2.wp.com/name-my-site/wp-content/themes/prostayllr/images/gravatar.gif:1
>   location of gravatar is:
>   http://name-my-site/wp-content/themes/prostayllr/images/gravatar.gif

Comment: Does the Gravatar URL really have a `:1` suffix? If so, that's a port specification, and a web server is most unlikely to be listening on such a port.

Comment: Aside: the function `prostayll_comment()` is not really how to build web applications, mainly because all manner of HTML is trapped in echo/print statements. I know that WordPress plugins are not normally well-engineered, but that just is not maintainable. There are plenty of templating engines you can use to separate out your view from your logic.